# take top 3 count from two table SQLSERVER 2008

Tags: sql, join

I got two table in database :

```
dbo.Family 
dbo.Family_member 

relationship between them one-to-many
```

every family have one or more family_member 
the inner join condition is :

```
on dbo.Family.F_id = dbo.Family_member.FM_f_id
```

I need a query to get the id of the top 3 family who got the highest number of member in it

it's mean I should count how many record in family_member for each family then order them by decs and take the top 3

could you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a "group by" on family id field; the query would go like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 dbo.Family.F_id
FROM dbo.Family 
INNER JOIN dbo.Family_member
ON dbo.Family.F_id = dbo.Family_member.FM_f_id
GROUP BY dbo.Family.F_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select TOP 3 *, (select count(dbo.Family_member.FM_f_id) 
from dbo.Family_member where dbo.Family_member.FM_f_id = dbo.Family.F_id) 
winners from dbo.Family order by winners desc
```